# How strict is ST

Tags: haskell

How strict is are the [STRef](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-STRef.html)s in the ST Monad? If I write something to an STRef, can I be sure it will be fully evaluated without space leaks?

Answer (score 6):

This is the kind of thing you can easily test yourself.

```
Prelude Data.STRef Control.Monad.ST> :{
| runST $ do
|   newSTRef (error "strict!")
|   return "not strict!"
| :}
"not strict!"
```

Comment: STrefs are lazy but the monad itself is strict...err well as strict as a monad can be

Answer (score 6):

The `ST` monad itself is strict, in that it enforces strict event ordering.  Intuitively, when you evaluate `runST` you won't get any information out "until" all reads and writes from memory are done.  But, that is about it when it comes to enforcing strictness.  For example, `STRef` is lazy by default (a strict version exists).  You might want to recover strictness like

```
writeSTRef r $! 7
```

As to avoiding space leaks...this is a more complicated problem.  Just using the right monad is not going to be good enough.